# Is "$k[X]^\ast= k^\ast$" preserved under finite surjective etale morphisms $Y \to X$ (for $k$ alg closed)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Let $X$ be a smooth and connected variety over $k$, with $k[X]^\ast = k^\ast$. Suppose that $f: Y \to X$ is a surjective finite etale map of $k$-varieties, with $Y$ connected as well.

> Is it true that $k[Y]^\ast = k^\ast$?

As a remark: I *don't* want to make properness assumptions on $X$ or $Y$ (properness would certainly imply the above).

Comment: The notation $k^*[X]$ does not seem to make any sense. I guess you mean the units in $k[X]$; the correct notation is $k[X]^*$.

Comment: @Relapsarian You are right, I'll edit it.